# How can I tell which DLC my friends have for their games?

Tags: steam

I'm looking at buying some DLC as a gift for a friend, but I want to double-check he doesn't already have it.  He's not online right now to simply ask, and you'd think with the ability to see our shared games, I should be able to tell anyway, but I'm not sure.  I could find out by buying a gift copy and seeing if it'll let me send it to him, but that's obviously a waste of money if he does have it.

Is there a way to tell if a friend already has a specific DLC, without buying a gift copy first?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

DLC's have their own store page. If I look at the base game store page for [Civ V](http://store.steampowered.com/app/8930/) for example, it shows me this in the right-hand-side:

[image: Base game friends]

If I then click (or hover) on the title of a DLC in the DLC list, (e.g. [Brave New World](http://store.steampowered.com/app/235580/)) the right-hand-side shows me which people on my friends list actually own that DLC.

[image: DLC list]

[image: DLC friends]

If your friend is already in that list, they have that DLC already.

Answer (score 1):

This question is on the [forums](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/626329820816271065). On there they say that you can add the game to your cart. Send to a friend. and look on your friends list. If they have it. They will not show up in the gifting list!

Hope this helps!